# Refreshing a selected item from an observable array

Tags: knockout.js

## Deleted

I asked [this question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124317/refreshing-a-selected-observable-when-parent-is-updated) but in a better way, and got the answer I needed.

#### [View new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124317/refreshing-a-selected-observable-when-parent-is-updated)

Comment: In your `refresh` you are recreating your people collection but your `selectedPerson` never changes so it points to the orginally selected person that is why you don't see changes on the UI. Instead of recreate update your viewmodel in the refresh: http://jsfiddle.net/AQ4PW/

Comment: @nemesv I think I've oversimplified my problem! I need to re-create the model (from returned JSON obtained from a web method) on an interval - so changes made outside of my app (i.e. directly to the data) will need to be reflected in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Your `viewModel.people` array is just a regular JavaScript array, not `ko.observableArray`. In your `viewModel.refresh` method, you are replacing it with another value. UI will not know that it's been updated.

Instead, define your `viewModel.people` property like this:

```
people: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(model.people, function (person) {
    return new Person(person);
}))
```

and in your `viewModel.refresh` method, use it as a function to change the value:

```
viewModel.people(ko.utils.arrayMap(model.people, function (person) {
    return new Person(person);
}));
```

There is one more problem with your approach (at least in your jsFiddle code). You are subscribing to `selectedPerson` property changes and calling `viewModel.refresh` there. Each time the `selectedPerson` is changed, it will trigger `refresh`, which will replace all people in your `viewModel.people` array, and hence, trigger the `selectedPerson` change again. So basically, you have an infinite loop there.

A better option would be just to add new person to the end of the existing list, or in your case, just update numbers for each person instead. Btw. `Person.numbers` should also be an `observableArray` in that case.

Comment: Good catch on the missing `observableArray` (unfortunately doesn't fix it) but have updated my question and fiddle with this. I'm aware of the infinite loop thing, but this is just an isolated test block to represent a specific issue so I'm not concerned.

Comment: @PaulAldred-Bann I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish. The fiddle seems to be working now. When modal is reopen, it shows new numbers. If you want open modal to refresh numbers live when they change, then you need to make an extra effort to update existing people array, and their person.numbers array and avoid recreating them each time.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after, for the modal UI to update showing the newly added items as they're added (but not from a push, from the actual observable array being re-created from items returned in the JSON).