# Refreshing a selected observable when parent is updated

Tags: knockout.js

*I asked this question previously, but it didn't get much response. It was obvious that I wasn't very clear what I was trying to achieve, so I'll try again.*

### [Here's the jsFiddle to play around with](http://jsfiddle.net/RY3aX/6/)

---

I'm working on an app that will (at an interval) call a web method, which will read a database and build up a JSON string to return which is used to construct my view model. When my view model changes I need to mutate all selected observables with the new data.

Take this as an example underlying model.

```
var model = {
    people: [
        { forename: "Test", surname: "Person", numbers: [1,2,3] },
        { forename: "Another", surname: "Test", numbers: [4,5,6] }
    ]
};
```

Simple enough, a table of people that when a row is clicked on a modal will pop up showing a list of `numbers` the selected person has.  While this modal is open, the data could be being updated behind the scenes so if [Test Person] is selected (and the modal pops up) and someone, somewhere adds `[7,8,9]` to their `numbers` then I need the modal to refresh showing these additions.

Here's a basic view model (using `ko.mapping` for brevity):

```
var viewModel = {
    people: ko.mapping.fromJS(model.people),
    selectedPerson: ko.observable(null),
    refresh: function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(model.people, function (person) {
            var last = person.numbers[person.numbers.length - 1];
            var newNumber = last + 1;
            person.numbers.push(newNumber);
        });
        ko.mapping.fromJS(model.people, this.people);
        console.log(ko.toJSON(this));
    }
};
```

When a row is clicked on, the person is stored in `selectedPerson` which makes my modal become visible in the UI (I'm using Zurb Foundation):

```
<div id="modal" class="reveal-modal" data-bind="if: selectedPerson">
```

This modal shows a table of `numbers` with a button named Update Observable - this calls a function to emulate the changes to the underlying model (in this case I'm taking the last item in `numbers` incrementing it by 1 and pushing it on). When this is done I then re-create my view model (using `ko.mapping` for brevity) and expect everything on the UI to be updated to reflect the change - all fine apart from the modal.

Looking at the JSON of my view model after re-mapping I can see that the view model has been updated correctly, but the `selectedPerson` hasn't. I assumed `selectedPerson` was a reference, not a copy, but I obviously assumed wrong and we end up with this.

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "forename": "Test",
            "surname": "Person",
            "numbers": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        },
        {
            "forename": "Another",
            "surname": "Test",
            "numbers": [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
        }
    ],
    "selectedPerson": {
        "forename": "Test",
        "surname": "Person",
        "numbers": [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

So I suppose my question is: how do I update `selectedPerson` (or in fact any other selected observable there may be) when the underlying model changes?

Comment: Your question is fairly long - could you summarize the problem somewhere at the end with a little more detail?  All you need to do to update a Knockout property is set the value.  If you are trying to update some properties on that selectedPerson and have it update the parent observableArray or something than I don't see that in your problem statement

Comment: The `ko.mapping.fromJS(model.people, this.people);` still empties and recreates your `people` collection. So your `selectedPerson` no longer references the current state. You need to tell the mapping plugin how it identify your items and update them:    `ko.mapping.fromJS(model.people, { key: function(item) { return item.forename }}, this.people);` http://jsfiddle.net/TY8LK/

Comment: @nemesv This is definitely more like what I was after, although I'm not using the mapping plugin in the actual app (it's something to think about though) I can certainly take the principles from it. If you add this as an answer I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `ko.mapping.fromJS(model.people, this.people)` empties and recreates your `people` collection. But your `selectedPerson` still references one of the old `person` object.

You need to tell the mapping plugin how you want to identify your items so it will update them:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(model.people, 
                 { key: function(item) { return item.forename; } }, 
                 this.people);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TY8LK).

Or as an alternative solution you can reset your `selectedPerson` to one of the  the newly created `person` object after the mapping:

```
this.selectedPerson(ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.people(), function(item){
        return item.forename() == this.selectedPerson().forename();
    }, this));
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZB58/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for taking the time it's very appreciated!